# Convert First-order Linear System to Second-order ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, homogeneous-equation

I'm just getting started on differential equations and am now looking at a task that asks to find the ordinary second-order differential equation that "underlies" a system of differential equations given by:

$\left(\begin{matrix}\dot u(t)\\\dot v(t)\\ \end{matrix} \right)=\left(\begin{matrix}0&1\\\frac{1}{1-t}&\frac{t}{t-1}\\ \end{matrix} \right)\left(\begin{matrix}v(t)\\u(t)\\ \end{matrix} \right)$

Now, I've read on the reduction of higher-order differential equations to systems, and came up with $x''(t)-\frac{1}{1-t}x'(t)-\frac{t}{t-1}x(t)=0$, which, by taking

$u=x, v=x'$

$u'=x'=v, v'=x''=\frac{1}{1-t}x'(t)+\frac{t}{t-1}x(t)$

reduces exactly to what I was given at the start, which is why I figured my solution was right. However, in the second equation, I am asked to show that $u(t)=\left(\begin{matrix}e^t\\e^t\\ \end{matrix} \right)$, which does not correspond with the second order differential equation that I came up with. Could anybody tell me where I made a mistake or what I should look into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is not correct you inverted $u,v$:
$$\left(\begin{matrix}\dot u(t)\\\dot v(t)\\ \end{matrix} \right)=\left(\begin{matrix}0&1\\\frac{1}{1-t}&\frac{t}{t-1}\\ \end{matrix} \right)\left(\begin{matrix}v(t)\\u(t)\\ \end{matrix} \right)$$
It should be:
$$\left(\begin{matrix}\dot u(t)\\\dot v(t)\\ \end{matrix} \right)=\left(\begin{matrix}0&1\\\frac{1}{1-t}&\frac{t}{t-1}\\ \end{matrix} \right)\left(\begin{matrix}u(t)\\v(t)\\ \end{matrix} \right)$$
So that the second order DE is:
$$x''(t)-\frac{t}{t-1}x'(t)-\frac{1}{1-t}x(t)=0$$

---

**Edit**

@psyph  Applying Liouville's formula I got this general solution:

$$|\phi (t)|=c_1 \exp \int \frac {t}{t-1} dt$$
$$|\phi (t)|=c_1e^t(t-1)$$
We also have that:
$$|\phi (t)|=u(t)e^t-v(t)e^t=e^t(u(t)-v(t))$$
$$\implies u(t)e^t-v(t)e^t=c_1e^t(t-1)$$
$$ u(t)-v(t)=c_1(t-1)$$
from the original equation we have:
$$u'(t)=v(t) \implies u'(t)-u(t)=-c_1(t-1)$$
using method of integrating factor
$$ (u(t)e^{-t})'=-c_1(t-1)e^{-t}$$
Integrate:
$$ u(t)e^{-t}=-c_1(-(t-1)e^{-t}-e^{-t})+c_2$$
$$  u(t)=-c_1(-(t-1)-1)+c_2e^{t}$$
$$ \implies u(t)=tc_1+c_2e^{t}$$
And for $v(t)$:
$$v(t)=u'(t)=c_1+c_2e^{t}$$
Finally :
$$\left(\begin{matrix} u(t)\\\ v(t)\\ \end{matrix} \right)=\left(\begin{matrix}c_1t+c_2e^t\\c_1+c_2e^t\\ \end{matrix} \right)$$
$$\left(\begin{matrix} u(t)\\\ v(t)\\ \end{matrix} \right)=c_1\left(\begin{matrix}t\\1\\ \end{matrix} \right)+c_2\left(\begin{matrix}e^t\\e^t\\ \end{matrix} \right)$$

Comment: Thanks, should I correct the error in my post? Also, if I wanna show that $u(t)=\left(\begin{matrix}e^t\\e^t\\ \end{matrix} \right)$, should I solve the second-order equation I just got with your help? I think I know how to do that, but it would be quite a bit of work...

Comment: Well you can add your solution @psyph so members can help you correct it

Comment: But isn't there an easier way to verify that $u(t)$ is a solution to the differential equation? Could I show that  $\left(\begin{matrix}e^t\\e^t\\ \end{matrix} \right)$ is a solution to the system of differential equations?

Comment: You can just plug that solution in the system yes. Note that $v=u'=(e^t,e^t)$ @psyph It's obvious that that $u(t)$ is a solution it takes two minutes to check it

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that, since the two $t$-factors will add to 1, but I thought it isn't sufficient. Thanks.

Comment: @psyph it's suffises to show that the solution you are given is a solution to  the system. Ansd it's obvious it's the case. But how comes you inverted the vector in the system ? Was it a mistake in your notes and book or else ?

Comment: Just a mistake in my notes, I copied the task from the board and I often get $u$ and $v$ confused when in a hurry...

Comment: I see ....because I have never seen that in any book lol @psyph

Comment: I have another question about a later sub-task, I hope it is okay that I ask it here since it's directly related to the first problem: in a later task, using Liouville formula I proved that for a second solution of the DES $v = (v_1, v_2)$, $e^t(v_2-v_1)=C(t-1)e^t$ holds true. Now using that identity as well as $v_2 = v_1'$, I'm supposed to find a solution for $v(t)$ that will also give me the general solution, but when simply solving the identity and trying for example method of integrating factor, I get stuck with an unsolvable integral. Do you have a hint if I'm missing something?

Comment: I got a solution that works fine @psyph

Comment: @psyph I added my solution in my answer ...I will add more lines if you need more details.

Comment: @psyph The integral is easy to evaluate and I got a solution that works fine. Maybe you made a mistake somewhere ?

Comment: @psyph I added a complete solution..i hope it helps ..

Answer (score 1):

Wow, thanks so much for helping me, yet again, really awesome!

Comment: Yw MJP I am happy if this helped you